# LinkedList, delete,insertion and interleave

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm practising with LinkedList and is trying to write the implementation for the functions  `delete_last_element()`,`insert_after()` and `interleave()`. 
But my code is not working (i.e. it does not do everything in the main function properly) .I've been searching through other similar posts in Stack Overflow but still couldn't figure out why. Any hints or help would be appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int key;
    string value;
    Node* next;
}; 

// Pre-condition: The head of a linked list is provided and a key-value 
// pair to insert.
// Post-condition: The linked list now contains that element at the front.
void insert( Node*& head, int key, string value) {

    Node * temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->value = value;

    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;

}

// Pre-condition: A linked list is provided.
// Post-condition: The linked list is printed to standard output.
void print( Node* head ) {
    Node* temp = head;
    while( temp != NULL ) {
    cout << "key: " << temp->key << " value: " << temp->value << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

// Pre-condition: The head of a linked list is provided.
// Post-condition: The last element of that linked list has been removed.

void delete_last_element( Node*& head )
{
    Node *temp = head;
    if (temp == NULL){
        cout << "The linkedList is empty, no node to delete!!" << endl;
    }

    if(temp->next == NULL){
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
        } 

        while(temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        delete temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;          
}

// Pre-condition: The head of a linked list is provided, and a key-value
// pair to insert after the indicated key.
// Post-condition: The linked list now contains that element.
void insert_after( Node*& head, int key, int newKey, string value )
{
    Node *node_ptr = head;
    Node *nodeToInsert = new Node;

    nodeToInsert->key = newKey;
    nodeToInsert->value = value;

    while(node_ptr !=NULL){

    if (node_ptr->key == key){
        nodeToInsert->next = node_ptr->next;
        node_ptr->next = nodeToInsert;
    }
    else node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
    }   
}

// Pre-condition: Two linked lists are provided.
// Post-condition: A linked list is returned that is the result of
// interleaving the elements from each list provided (e.g. {1, 2, 3} &
// { 4, 5, 6} would return {1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6}
Node* interleave( Node*& list1, Node*& list2 )
{
if(list1 == NULL)
    return list2;

if(list2 == NULL)
    return list1;

    Node *x=list1, *y=list2;

    while(x && y){
        Node *tmp = x->next;
        x->next = y;
        y = tmp;
        x= x->next;
    }
    return list1;

}

int main() {

    Node * list1 = NULL;
    Node * list2 = NULL;
    Node * list3 = NULL;
    Node * list4 = NULL;

    insert( list1, 1, "one");
    insert( list1, 2, "two");

    cout << "<1> Linked List 1..." << endl;
    print( list1 );

    insert( list2, 10, "ten");
    insert( list2, 9, "nine");
    insert( list2, 8, "eight");
    insert( list2, 7, "seven");
    insert( list2, 6, "six");

    cout << "<2> Linked List 2..." << endl;
    print( list2 );

    delete_last_element( list1 );
    cout << "<3> Linked List 1..." << endl;
    print( list1 );

    delete_last_element( list1 );
    cout << "<4> Linked List 1..." << endl;
    print( list1 );

    delete_last_element( list1 );
    cout << "<5> Linked List 1..." << endl;
    print( list1 );

    insert(list1, 11, "eleven");
    insert_after(list1, 11, 12, "twelve");
    cout << "<6> Linked List 1..." << endl;
    print( list1 );


    insert_after(list1, 13, 14, "fourteen");
    cout << "<7> Linked List 1..." << endl;
    print( list1 );

    list4 = interleave(list1, list2);
    cout << "<8> Linked List 4..." << endl;
    print( list4 );

    list4 = interleave(list1, list3);
    cout << "<9> Linked List 4..." << endl;
    print( list4 );

    list4 = interleave(list3, list3);
    cout << "<10> Linked List 4..." << endl;
    print( list4 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No answer for you, but a suggestion on how to debug: Simplify. Change main so that you can reproduce a problem using, say, just insert. You can run the program through a debugger and look at the values of each variable as you go, or perform a series of `cout << [some value] << endl;` to try and get an idea what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem:

```
    while(temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    delete temp->next;
    temp->next = NULL;
```

Here, you are deleting a NULL pointer.

In function insertAfter, you are changing the **original** list head, if I'm correct. Don't pass a reference, just an ordinary pointer is enough.

Comment: I'm a beginner to c++ and I don't quite understand this sentence "you are changing the original list head, if I'm correct. Don't pass a reference, just an ordinary pointer is enough." Can you explain more about it?

Comment: If you pass a reference to a variable as a function argument, whenever you change that reference, you are changing the original variable. This means that by passing Node*& head, you will change the original list head. Also, you are doing the same thing in the delete function too. This messes up your list.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem:

In delete_last_element:

```
if (temp == NULL){
        cout << "The linkedList is empty, no node to delete!!" << endl;
    }

if(temp->next == NULL){ ...
```

You should `return;` if temp == null (after you cout), or else it will try and check `temp->next == NULL`, which will cause a segfault.